# How do I convert this piece of ruby code to c#?

Tags: c#, ruby

I have this piece of code in Ruby:

```
server_id = "0xf9f1e687"

actions = "S(#{Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i.to_s})S(12946;server:#{server_id.to_i(16).to_s})"
```

How do I write it in C#?

Closest I got is:

```
int server_id = (int)new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter()
                .ConvertFromString("0xf9f1e687");

var actions = "S(" + DateTime.Now.Second + ")S(12946;server:" + server_id + ")";
```

Comment: So you wrote it in C#. Does it work as expected or not?

Comment: No, conversion from string to Int fails.

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem is only with converting your string to int - I will address just that. Number `0xf9f1e687` is out of range for C# `Int32`. `Int32.MaxValue` is `0x7FFFFFFF`. That is why your conversion gives wrong (negative) value. It would be better if it just throw an exception, but it does not. To fix, use either `long` (`Int64`) or unsigned int (`UInt32`):

```
var server_id = (uint) new UInt32Converter()
     .ConvertFromString("0xf9f1e687");
var server_id = (long) new Int64Converter()
            .ConvertFromString("0xf9f1e687");
```

Alternative way:

```
var server_id = uint.Parse("0xf9f1e687".Replace("0x", ""), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```